# JFreeChart highlight bar chart item on click immediately

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a bar chart using JFreeChart, I have it setup to highlight the selected (by click) and mouseover bars. The bars change colour when highlighted. However, they take about 1.5 seconds to update - my guess is its the next time the dataset changes.

How can I force the renderer to be called immediately?

Answer (score 1):

In typical good timing I figure out the answer right after posting:

```
    objChart.getCategoryPlot().datasetChanged(new DatasetChangeEvent(cme, dataset));
```

Nice and easy.